# translate Java code to C

Tags: java, c, pointers, translation

I am new in C and apparently I've got some problems with understanding all the memory and pointer things.
So I have the following Java code:

```
public class Question_10
{
   public static void sortInt(int[] array)
   {
      int top = 0;
      while (top < array.length - 1)
      {
         if (array[top] < array[top + 1])
         {
            top++;
         }
         else
         {
            int temp = array[top];
            array[top] = array[top + 1];
            array[top + 1] = temp;
            if (top > 0)
            {
               top--;
            }
         }
         System.out.println(top);
      }
   }

   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      int[] arr = {5, 6, 10, 1, 45, 3};

      sortInt(arr);
      System.out.println();
   }

}
```

Aaand, I've done the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void sortInt(int arrayInput[])
{
    int top = 0;
    int arrLen = sizeof(arrayInput)/(sizeof(int);
    while(top < arrLen - 1)
    {
        if(arrayInput[top] < arrayInput[top+1])
        {
            top++;
        }
        else
        {
            int temp = arrayInput[top];
            arrayInput[top] = arrayInput[top + 1];
            arrayInput[top + 1] = temp;
            if(top > 0)
            {
                top--;
            }
        }
        printf("%i", top);
    }
}
void main()
{

    int array[] = {5, 6, 10, 1, 45, 3};
    sortInt(array);
    return 0;
}
```

Of course I get a lot of errors:

```
$ gcc Question10.c
Question10.c: In function `sortInt':
Question10.c:6: error: parse error before ';' token
Question10.c: At top level:
Question10.c:16: error: `top' undeclared here (not in a function)
Question10.c:16: warning: data definition has no type or storage class
Question10.c:17: error: `temp' undeclared here (not in a function)
Question10.c:17: warning: data definition has no type or storage class
Question10.c:18: error: parse error before "if"
Question10.c:23: error: parse error before string constant
Question10.c:23: error: conflicting types for 'printf'
Question10.c:23: note: a parameter list with an ellipsis can't match an empty parameter name list declaration
Question10.c:23: error: conflicting types for 'printf'
Question10.c:23: note: a parameter list with an ellipsis can't match an empty parameter name list declaration
Question10.c:23: warning: data definition has no type or storage class
Question10.c: In function `main':
Question10.c:30: warning: `return' with a value, in function returning void
Question10.c:27: warning: return type of 'main' is not `int'
Question10.c:31:2: warning: no newline at end of file
Question10.c: At top level:
Question10.c:16: error: storage size of `arrayInput' isn't known
Question10.c:17: error: storage size of `arrayInput' isn't known
```

Maybe you could give me any suggestion on what's wrong and some general guidance will be helpful, because I am really getting lost in these "object" things in C.

Comment: Then stop using them. Port algorithms, not code.

Comment: The errors are obvious, more in line 6.

Comment: Important note: `int arrLen = sizeof(arrayInput)/sizeof(int);` does not work in `sortInt()`. The argument the function receives is a pointer to the first element of `array`, so you set `arrLen` to `sizeof(int*) / sizeof(int)` regardless of the array's length. You must pass the length as a parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a syntax error on this line:

`int arrLen = sizeof(arrayInput)/(sizeof(int);`

Try instead with:
`int arrLen = sizeof(arrayInput)/sizeof(int);`

If you start by fixing that then you might solve some of the other problems you have. If not, take one at a time.

Another error that I can see is that you declared your main method as `void main()` and you call `return 0;`. According to the C standard, main() method should return `int`, so change the declaration.

Comment: "Try instead with" --- No, don't; that yields the wrong value because arrayInput is a pointer (due to decay), not an array.

Comment: @JimBalter Good point. I was more focused on the syntax error than on what the expected result would be.

Answer (score 1):

I made it works.

```
   void sortInt(int arrayInput[], int arrLen)
    {
        int top = 0;
        while(top < arrLen - 1)
        {
            if(arrayInput[top] < arrayInput[top+1])
            {
                top++;
            }
            else
            {
                int temp = arrayInput[top];
                arrayInput[top] = arrayInput[top + 1];
                arrayInput[top + 1] = temp;
                if(top > 0)
                {
                    top--;
                }
            }
            printf("%i", top);
        }
    }

    int main()
    {
        int array[] = {5, 6, 10, 1, 45, 3};
        sortInt(array, sizeof(array)/sizeof(int));
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: @YogendraSingh Because what the function receives as argument is a pointer to the first element of the array. There is no way to determine the array size inside the function.

Comment: @YogendraSingh No, it of course cannot (C programming .101) -- arrayInput is a pointer, not an array.